# functions.php file not running my JavaScript in js folder

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm simply trying to add a JS accordion to my Wordpress blog but the accordion.js file seems not to be loading through the functions.php file.

However, if I load the js code through  in the header.php file, it runs perfectly.

This is the functions.php code:

```
// enqueue script
function my_scripts_method() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-accordion',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
    array('jquery')
    );
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

It's a simple code that is flying around everywhere and seems to be working for everyone else, except me of course.

The interesting thing is that once the js code loads through the header.php inclusion, the stylesheet for the the accordion runs.

What I have noticed is that I cannot seem to link to and load files from functions.php file. This is not the only file that I've had difficulty loading. The same thing happens to the file below:

```
function wpb_load_fa() { 
wp_enqueue_style( 'wpb-fa', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_load_fa' );
```

I've tried all I could to load the font-awesome.min.css to no avail.

Would could I be doing wrong with my file referencing structure from within the functions.php file? The directory structure were created just as instructed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wp_register_script(); ?
the function is

```
wp_register_script( string $handle, string|bool $src, string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )
```

[check here for docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/)

Comment: I'm just a simple user of wordpress and not that much into coding at the moment. If you could break that down a bit... that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it because you are logged in as the admin, and your code only adds the js if the current user is not admin. You can remove the check and the code will look like this:

```php
// enqueue script
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-accordion',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
    array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen, but still no chance. As I said it is not only this script that has this issue. The obvious other one is the font-awesome issue. The font-awesome has to do with my main menu on my blog where arrows where supposed to show, but up till now, it has simply refused to work. 
They only get to work when I call try calling them directly from the header, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you've not logged in with admin user,Also make sure jQuery is included before this script you've included. Because your script is depended on jQuery.

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
array('jquery')
);
```

Comment: Can you help me a standard code to include jQuery as suggested as I have no clue on doing that. Thanks.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('jquery')

Answer (score 0):

here is little bit issue in your code

Replace this

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js'
```

to

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/accordion.js',
```

i inform to you

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function
```

is only for accessing wordpress global style.css file

Comment: I've earlier on notice that and tried that suggestion but still ended up the same. I don't but has anyone really experienced something close this and what was their way out? Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    // wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-accordion', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/accordion.js',array());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Comment: Hi Manog, thanks for the response. I tried the code but still the same result. I don't feel it has anything to do with being logged in as admin because the same issue affects my /fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css file. Checking it online through mediums which I am not admin has always yield the same results. It's just frustratng...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, including some additional details and information can greatly improve its long-term value, help others understand it, and therefore can result in more upvotes. Consider adding some explanatory text